# LINQ Min() and Max() optimisation

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having some trouble doing it right.

I need to pick the minimum and maximum for a list inside a list inside a list

Any thought how I can create a optimized type?

```
var range = allFilteredCars
            .SelectMany(car => car.LeasingPlans
                .SelectMany(plan => plan.Durations)
                .Select(a => a.MonthlyPrice))
            .ToList();

        var min = range.Min();
        var max = range.Max();
```

The last `Min()` and `Max()` doesn't feel right.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get around the multiple `SelectMany`s but an Ordering in the query will get rid of the Min/Max. This should be quicker as you are then only sorting once:

```
var range = allFilteredCars
        .SelectMany(car => car.LeasingPlans
            .SelectMany(plan => plan.Durations)
            .Select(a => a.MonthlyPrice))
            .OrderBy(a => a))
        .ToList();

    var min = range[0]; // get the first
    var max = range[range.Count-1];  // get the last
```

Comment: I dunno, sorting is O(n lg(n)). Getting the first & last item can be done in O(n).

Comment: You don't need to sort to get the min() and max(). These can be found in a single pass.

Comment: Agree with other commenters - this is not the optimal way of doing things and is in fact worse than the original method once n is more than a handful of items.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of only one way to calculate `min` and `max` just by iterating one time on the entire collection which can be done using `foreach` loop

```
var min = Int32.MaxValue;
var max = Int32.MinValue;
foreach(var filteredCard in allFilteredCars)
{
    foreach(var leasingPlan in filteredCard.LeasingPlans) 
    {
        foreach(var car in leasingPlan.Durations) 
        {
          if(car.MonthlyPrice < min)
            min = car.MonthlyPrice;
          else if(car.MonthlyPrice > max)
            max = car.MonthlyPrice;
        }
     }
}
```

> Assuming `MonthlyPrice` is of `Int`

Comment: My thoughts too. You go from iterating the list twice to iterating it once.

Comment: This is indeed the optimal solution (the second `if` can even become `else if` since value cannot be both less than min and greater than max). LINQ has no way to calculate multiple aggregates in a single pass (except `Aggregate`, which basically is ugly `foreach`).

Answer (score 3):

We will do a *bad thing*: a linq expression with a side effect.

```
int? min = null;
int? max = null;

allFilteredCars
    .SelectMany(car => car.LeasingPlans
        .SelectMany(plan => plan.Durations))
            .Select(a =>
            {
                if (min == null || a.MonthlyPrice < min.Value)
                {
                    min = a.MonthlyPrice;
                }

                if (max == null || a.MonthlyPrice > max.Value)
                {
                    max = a.MonthlyPrice;
                }

                return true;
            }).All(x => x);
```

In the end you don't really seem to need the `range` result... You only want the `Min()` and `Max()`, so we calculate it, and force the whole `IEnumerable<>` to be elaborated through the use of `All()`.

You have to replace `int?` with the type of `MonthlyPrice`!